# Cannot access the checkbox object from nested static class

Tags: android, android-studio, gridview

I created a grid view for images and added checkbox to select images but the check box is recycled so  Other images also selected.

This is my model class

```
class ImageItem
{ 
    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }
    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }
}
```

This is my getView().

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent ) {
        View row = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (row == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent,false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            //find resource...
            holder.image= (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.image);
            holder.imageTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.check = (CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.checkbox) ;
           row.setTag(holder);
       } else {
         holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
       }

       holder.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
       holder.check.setFocusable(false);

       holder.check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           if (data.get(position).isSelected()) {
              data.get(position).setSelected(false);
           } else {
             data.get(position).setSelected(true);
           }    
        }
    });


    holder.check.setChecked(data.get(position).isSelected());
    holder.imageTitle.setText(data.get(position).getTitle());

    holder.image.setImageBitmap(data.get(position).getImage());
    return row;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView imageTitle;
    ImageView image;
    public  static CheckBox check;
}
```

I also tried to save state in boolean array but that also resulted in same problem. I know many solutions are provided but nothing worked for me. Please read my code completely. what am i missing?

**After suggested edits**
I made the checkbox non static and created a object in mainactivity to set visibl on longclick.

```
 static class ViewHolder {
    TextView imageTitle;
    ImageView image;
    CheckBox check;
     CheckBox method() {


        return check;
    }
gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

GridViewAdapter.ViewHolder vh = new GridViewAdapter.ViewHolder();
            check = vh.method();
for(int index=0;index< adapterView.getChildCount();index++) {
             View nextchild = (adapterView.getChildAt(index));
           CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) nextchild.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
             checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Iam getting error as classcast exception at line

```
check = vh.method();
```

**Thank you so much for those who helped so far**

Answer (score 0):

maybe because you use

```
public  static CheckBox check;
```

try to remove `static` like this

```
public  CheckBox check;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why should I change it. Just asking to learn

Comment: I will tell you when you use static the state of the checkbox become common so any change in any position will effect to all other checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

First make your checkbox non static

```
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView imageTitle;
    ImageView image;
    CheckBox check;
}
```

Then change your `onClick` method like below

```
holder.check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Checkbox checkbox = (Checkbox)view;
        data.get(position).setSelected(checkbox.isChecked);
        notifyItemChanged(position); // Important one
    }
});
```

Comment: Can I know why should I remove static? I need to access the check box in another class how to do that. Thanks for answer

Comment: Because we want **view holder instance for each row/item**, for more information learn [static members vs instance members](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/293478/what-are-the-differences-between-class-variables-and-instance-variables-in-java).

Would be better if you follow the answer and confirm whether it worked or not ?

Comment: I am in college. Will definitely try and update as soon as I reach home :)

Comment: whole summary:1) I want the checkbox to be visible after Longclick.2) So i made checkbox static to access in main activity as GridViewAdapter.ViewHolder.check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: I think this is the another question, look at the question what you have mentioned. We have addressed the original question here, I think you should post another question or modify the existing question accordingly.

Comment: Ok Sharma I will.

Comment: Mark the answer accepted if it has fixed the original issue mentioned in the question.

Comment: Still I cannot check the scroll problem, so i think its not fixed. Made edits, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

remove static modifier from `check`, and you can try this:

```
...

private final SparseBooleanArray mCheckedItemPositions = new SparseBooleanArray();

...

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent ) {
    ...

    holder.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            mCheckedItemPositions.put(position, isChecked);
        }
    });

    holder.check.setChecked(mCheckedItemPositions.get(position));
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you share link for any sparsebooleanarray tutorial.